# Basic PHP Array in html table

Tags: php, html

I was doing a simple PHP array table, but the result of my code is not what I've expected,

```
<?php 
    $names = array (
        'First Name' => 
            array('Alfre', 'Beka', 'Charlie'),
        'Middle Name' =>
            array('Brom', 'Tiv', 'Clore'),
        'Last Name' =>
            array('Adani', 'Filial', 'Chrome'),
    );
    
    echo '<table border="1">';
    foreach($names as $name => $indv_name) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo "<th>$name</th>";
                foreach($indv_name as $per_name) {
                    echo '<td>',$song, '</td>';
                }
                echo '</tr>';
            }
    echo '</table>';
    ?>
```

The result of the array of this code is echoed horizontally, can anyone help me to echo it vertically?

Here's my output example:

```
firstname -> value, value, value
middlename -> value, value, value
lastname -> value, value, value
```

Output that I want to expect:

```
firstname - middlename - lastname
  value   -   value    -  value
  value   -   value    -  value
  value   -   value    -  value
          -   value    -  value
                       -  value
```

And whenever I add value in the array, it won't break the line.
Sorry for the late edit

Comment: Please show an example of the result you're expecting and then what you're getting.

Comment: It would make more sense to organize the array by grouping by the person themself rather than the name type. i.e. `'Alfre' => ['First Name' => 'Alfre', 'Middle Name' => 'Brom', 'Last Name' => 'Adani']`

Comment: I've already edited my question, to make it more understandable, sorry for late edit

Comment: you can use display:flex intead table

Answer (score 1):

A basic way

```php
$names = array (
        'First Name' => 
            array('Alfre', 'Beka', 'Charlie'),
        'Middle Name' =>
            array('Brom', 'Tiv', 'Clore'),
        'Last Name' =>
            array('Adani', 'Filial', 'Chrome'),
);
echo "<table>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($names as $key => $value) {
        echo "<th>$key</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    foreach ($names as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
            echo "<td>$value</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but whenever I add value in array, it won't add vertically but on horizontally.

Comment: It still lack for vertical allignment of every value in each variable whenever I add another value~